# Laravel 5 Intervention Image throwing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, image, laravel, amazon-ec2, intervention

I'm having issues using the Intervention Image library.
It works on my localhost, but when i try using it on my server, it throws a 500 Internal Server Error.
I suspect that I am missing some kind of php module or something, but i'm not sure. (It's an amazon EC2 server)
It's failing on this line:

```
$image = Image::make($file)->encode('jpg', 90);
```

$file is a base64 encoded image file.
It's throwing a 500, but no error message of any kind.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Can you fetch the apache log files on that server?

Comment: Check your error logs located in `/storage/logs`

Comment: Did you run `composer update` command on server after adding Intervention Image library?

Comment: @Blaatpraat How do i check apache log files?

Comment: @aynber There is nothing in /storage/logs

Comment: @patryk-uszynski yeah i have run composer update

Comment: On this page you can see how you can check the apache logs on an EC2 server: http://www.bigappledesigns.com/blog/linux/how-to-access-apache-web-server-httpd-error-logs-for-amazon-ec2-linux-and-most-other-linux-varieties-also/

Comment: @Blaatpraat i found it. This is what i got:
62.242.39.251 - - [13/Jan/2017:13:57:24 +0000] "POST /api/users/1/feeds HTTP/1.1" 500 206 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved it looking through the log. 
Aparently "something" didn't have permission to write to the log file and that caused the "no error message being outputted" part of my question.
Now i get the error: "GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation"

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

That solved my problem :)